# Map not loaded using openlayers 3 on firefox and ie/edge

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3, tiles

I'm using openlayers 3 and have a tiled image (not a geographical map) and it's working great in chrome, but not in firefox or ie/edge. I keep getting the following error:

```
IndexSizeError: Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount
```

I think this may have something to do with the projection or the fact that I'm not using lan/lat coordinates.

Here is a simple example (also available at [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/vorihatedu/1/edit?html,css,js,output))

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>XYZ</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.13.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.13.0/build/ol.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map" style="width: 500px; height: 500px; border: 1px solid #000;"></div>
    <script>
 
  var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
   new ol.layer.Tile({
     source: new ol.source.XYZ({
    url: 'http://shimz.me/example/leaflet/image/mother_map/TileGroup0/{z}-{x}-{y}.jpg',
    wrapX: false
     })
   })
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
   center: [0,0],
   zoom: 1
    })
  });

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any idea how to fix that ?

Comment: working fine on my Firefox 43.0.4

Comment: In firefox 42 it doesn't work, also in edge and IE 11 and below

Comment: Looks like something is wrong with the images at zoom level 1. if you set `zoom: 2` in your snippet, it works.

Comment: I would be happy to know whats wrong... And why it works in chrome and the latest firefox. Also setting zoom to 2 will help only until the user change the zoom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So... after a long long research the problem was that the tiles size wasn't equal, on the edges instead of 256x256 sometimes it was 256xsometing-smaller-then-256

After squaring all tiles to 256x256 it works great!

Comment: I think I got kinda the same problem - do you remember why sometimes the tiles were smaller than 256? And how did you correct that? With an Imagemagick script, or something?

Comment: @F3L1X79 you can use convert with -extent 256x256 and gravity to the right direction according to the tile location (on the right or bottom)